# Find complementary pairs in array in Java

Tags: java

I am attempting to find how many pairs of values in a given array of integers sum to a specified value k. The logic works if the list contains duplicate values, provided each value has only one complement in the list to sum to k. The issue is that if multiple complements to a given value exist in the list, only one match is counted.

What I have attempted so far is as follows:

```
  int numberOfWays(int[] arr, int k) {
    // Write your code here
    int output = 0;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      int complement = k - arr[i];
      if(map.containsKey(complement)) {
        output++;
      }
      map.put(arr[i],i);
      System.out.println(map);
    }
    return output;
  }
```

This works for a case as such: k = 6, arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
However, it doesn't work when there are more than two duplicates: k = 6, arr = [1, 5, 3, 3, 3]

For the case that doesn't work the expected result is 4 but the actual is 3.

I can't seem to figure out why that's the case. Any ideas?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by “doesn’t work”? Please provide actual vs expected output for the input that “doesn’t work”.

Comment: edited the question @Bohemian

Comment: What is the input and what is the output as per question??

Comment: @youngdev your description of the issue with your output remans unclear, which seems to be because your understanding of the homework question is unclear. I’ve edited the question for clarity, please roll back *and correct* if I guessed wrong from the context clues—if I guessed right please think on what the key differences are. It is the ability to understand what logic you are being asked for that is critical in both class and industry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it didn't work for the second one is, 3 should match 2 other 3s. But map only supports one. The change should be:

```java
 int numberOfWays(int[] arr, int k) {
    // Write your code here
    int output = 0;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      int complement = k - arr[i];
      int count = map.getOrDefault(arr[i], 0);
      if(map.containsKey(complement)) {
        count = map.get(complement);
        output = output + count; // 2 3s, should match twice.
      }
      map.put(arr[i], count + 1);
      System.out.println(map);
    }
    return output;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your method randomly fails.  I recommend you run it through some iterations of varying lengths of `arr` as well as altering the `k` values.  Here is one, for a `k=27` and `arr = [3, 16, 18, 6, 14, 5, 5, 14, 22, 1]`  it should be a count of 2.

Comment: @WJS, Thanks for point out this. Find the bug, should use `int count = map.getOrDefault(arr[i], 0);` I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.  It works on three principles.

- do a frequency count of the supplied array.
- for values of `k` that are even, and `arr[i] == k/2` the count is `(v(v-1)/2` where `v`
  is the value for that key.  So if k = `8` and the array contains `four 4's`, then the count, `v` would be `4` and the sum combinations would be `6`.
- for values that don't meet the above, the count is the product of the two summands freqencies.  So if `k = 8` and there are three `3's` and two `5's` the combinations would be `three x two  == 6`.
- the total count is the sum of all the above computations for each pair of summands that add to `k`

```
static int numberOfWays(int[] arr, int k) {
    int count = 0;
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    // accumulate a frequency count values
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        map.compute(arr[i], (key, val) -> val == null ? 1 : val + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
    // copy keys to list for iteration to avoid
    // concurrent mod exception when removing keys from
    // map.  This works better than using an iterator.
    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    for (int key : keys) {
        if ((k&1) == 0 && map.containsKey(key) &&  key == k/2) {
            int v = map.get(key) - 1;
            count = count + ((v * (v + 1)) / 2);
        } else if (map.containsKey(k-key)) {
            System.out.println("trying");
            count += (map.get(key) * map.get(k - key));
        }

        map.remove(key);
    }
    return count;
}
```